# Fully transparent status bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to set transparent status bar in my Flutter App, but this does not make status bar fully transparent, it's like some dark color with opacity (the app has white background):
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPrR6.png)

And this is how I set status bar color in the `build` method of the `App` class:

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    // Not pretty much needed in this example, I'm just setting the color
    // for my nav bar to fit the theme
    systemNavigationBarColor: theme.current.primaryColor,
));
```

## What I have tried:

- Set `SystemUiOverlayStyle` in the `ThemeData` -> didn't help

Comment: make sure you hot restart the app in order to see the changes after applying below answers

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved my issue by setting to false `SystemUiOverlayStyle.systemStatusBarContrastEnforced` to `false`.
Apparently, flutter was forcing contrast and automatically set background for transparent black and icons white, while I needed black icons on transparent background (hence white because of app's background).

Big thanks for everybody who have tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

If that's not working then you can try this:

> Add this in your main method like this

```
void main() {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 //
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  systemNavigationBarColor: theme.current.primaryColor
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));
 //
 runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

This will make all your screen's status bar transparent.

Let me know if this doesn't help you.

Comment: It will help, but I want status bar to be transparent because in my app there are more than 1 theme. I have a lot of bugs with management of status bar color when changing the app theme, so the easiest thing to do is to make status bar transparent.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can try the edited version now.
@undermouse

Comment: I've tried updated version, still no result.

Comment: Did you add the code in the main() method?
Also before applying my approach, comment everywhere else where you have added the logic to change the colour of the status bar.

Comment: The issue is not in that color does not change. It changes, for example, if I set it to `Colors.red`, status bar becomes red as expected. It's something with transparent is not actually rendered is transparent, for some reason.

Comment: Can you show the code of the file where you are adding the code to change the color of the status bar.

Comment: Of course, here it is: https://pastebin.com/Ebc6it7V

Comment: did you add the code for making the status bar transparent in the main method and commenting everywhere else?

Comment: Yes, it's basically the only place where the status bar is configured. I'm 100% sure it with how this transparent color is handled in android. Maybe I need some config in `styles.xml`, idk.

Answer (score 0):

Use AppBar's systemOverlayStyle property

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark
            .copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent),
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image: Transparent statusbar]

Comment: I've set styling for the status bar using `ThemeData.appBarTheme.systemOverlayStyle`, also I've tried your method. None of them work.

Comment: Can you try removing systemOverlayStyle from everywhere and have it placed on some appbar?

Comment: Nothing changes. I think, that's some issue with the transparency configuration in `.android` files. Because it works fine if I set status bar color to something other that `Colors.transparent`. Any thoughts what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sample code to have custom statusBar color :

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
/*  appBar: AppBar(), */ //  <==== solution worked when no appBar
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.red, // < ===  specific color for status bar
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(child: Text("Sample"))),
      ),
    ));}
```

Comment: Nope, it gives the same results with not fully transparent status bar

Comment: you need status bar with specific color ? or you need hide status bar  completely?

Comment: I need it to be transparent. Like in telegram, for example, so I can draw my colors underneath it.

Comment: you can see in flutter counter app ,  by default appbar not specific color and transparent. may be your customized theme change them (the darkness of the theme will not be ineffective.).

Answer (score 0):

in the main.dart I have changed the void main() in the following way...

```
void main() {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

 // makes Smartphone Statusbar transparent
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark));

 runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

worked for me : )